# Passing non-printable ascii codes as java argument

Tags: java

I am trying to run a compiled java program with a password as the argument. When trying however it never validates because the very first character I try to send is the form feed character but its reading it as the separate characters when it saves it to a string rather than as a character with code 12. I was wondering if anyone knew how to pass a string of ascii codes to it. 
Edit: The Java class in question is a simple hashing script that keeps a running total of the character values of an entered string multiplied together in sequence and then compares the to a predefined number. Ive reversed the algorithm to the point where I have the character codes which will compare to the answer correctly but I have been unable to pass it as an argument.

Comment: Question is unclear to me.Can you post the code?

Comment: I'm not sure that would be ok but I can give a clearer idea. Give me just one minute ill update the question.

Comment: This is most likely a shell/command prompt or OS issue. Please identify those and give an example of running the program with arguments that don't include control characters.